# ons-buttons stay grey(pressed) after clicking on it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, onsen-ui, monaca

I'm actually developping an application and i want to edit/save an item. The problem is that ons-buttons stay greyed(pressed) after clicking on it. Anyone have an idea ? I'm developping on Monaca with Onsen-ui and angularjs. Here is an example:

```
         <div style="padding: 10px 9px" ng-show="edit">
        <ons-button ng-click="edit=!edit" modifier="large" style="margin: 0 auto;"><ons-icon icon="fa-edit"></ons-icon>
          Editer 
        </ons-button>
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 10px 9px" ng-show="!edit">
         <ons-row>
            <ons-col class="content-padded">
               <ons-button modifier="large" ng-click="edit=!edit">
                  Cancel
               </ons-button>
            </ons-col>
            <ons-col class="content-padded">
               <ons-button  modifier="large" ng-click="edit=!edit">
                  OK
               </ons-button>
            </ons-col>
     </ons-row>
     </div>
```

Comment: I forgot it's on android 5.0

Comment: Does this behavior still happen if you remove the `ng-click` directive? If not, what kind of behavior is triggered by the click? Is it just he `ng-show`?

Comment: At the moment, the ng-click is used to hide/show the appropriate div when the content is editable or not. if i remove the ng-show, it works nice but i want to display Edit button or Cancel/Ok buttons in case of modification.